# Javascript to "fix" all hrefs of class with regex

Tags: javascript

Say I have a bunch of links on a page like:

```
<a class="eg-vimeo1-element-0 eg-post-14" href="http://255972693" target="_self"><i class="eg-icon-play"></i></a>
```

And I want to change every `http://255972693` to `https://vimeo.com/video/255972693`

I tried this to see my hrefs:

```js
let e = document.getElementsByClassName("eg-vimeo1-element-0");
for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
  console.log(e[i].href);
  console.log(e[i].href.replace("http://", "https://vimeo.com/video"));
}
```

```html
<a class="eg-vimeo1-element-0 eg-post-14" href="http://255972693" target="_self"><i class="eg-icon-play"></i></a>
```

But it converts the href to an IP and gives results like

```
http://vimeo.com/video/15.65.213.85/
```

Comment: Is it the entire code you intended to post?

Comment: Don't do this in JS. Fix the output from your backend or wherever these links are generated.

Comment: I think the problem is that if you console.log the href before you do anything, it has already converted the number into an ip address - may be because it is an invalid domain name?

Comment: @Pete How do I prevent the conversion? It's not a domain at all ... yet. I need to "fix" it.

Comment: use `getAttribute`- was typing out an answer but someone beat me to it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will work if you use `getAttribute` on the href property.

```js
const e = document.getElementsByClassName("eg-vimeo1-element-0")

for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
  const href = e[i].getAttribute('href');
  e[i].href = href.replace("http://", "https://vimeo.com/video/");
}
```

```html
<a class="eg-vimeo1-element-0 eg-post-14" href="http://255972693">link</a>
```

Here's the [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buw5L0pg/6/).

And to preserve the comment from Niet the Dark Absol in case it disappears:

> "The reason this works and `.href` doesn't is because `.href` is the resolved URL, and `http://1234567` is interpreted as an IP address in decimal form."

Comment: The reason this works and `.href` doesn't is because `.href` is the *resolved* URL, and `http://1234567` is interpreted as an IP address in decimal form.

Comment: Thanks, @NiettheDarkAbsol. I had no idea why it was happening.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```js
let e = document.getElementsByClassName("eg-vimeo1-element-0");
for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
  var href = e[i].getAttribute('href');
  console.log('previous href: ', href);
  
  e[i].setAttribute('href', href.replace("http://", "https://vimeo.com/video/"));
  
  console.log('new href:', e[i].getAttribute('href'));
}
```

```html
<a class="eg-vimeo1-element-0 eg-post-14" href="http://255972693" target="_self"><i class="eg-icon-play"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `getAttribute`

```
let e = document.getElementsByClassName("eg-vimeo1-element-0");
 for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
  var url = e[i].getAttribute('href');
  alert(url.replace("https://", "https://vimeo.com/video/"));

}
```